# Почему всплывающая картинка появляется не под блоком вызывающим её появление?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Функции `JS` вызываются из тега `i`, по идее картинка должна появляться прямо под этим тегом, но на деле она появляется где то сильно ниже. Как это можно исправить? Чтобы увидеть - наведите на цифры под текстом, увидите, что появилась маленькая горизонтальная прокрутка - это картинка создалась)

```js
var image = document.createElement("img");

function showImage(element, event, url) {
  //console.log(element);
  image.className = "prepending-image";
  image.src = url;
  image.style.position = "absolute";
  image.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
  image.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
  image.style.width = "100px";
  image.style.height = "100px";
  return element.prepend(image);
}

function hideImage(element, event) {
  element.removeChild(image);
}
```

```css
.ThisDay-default-index {
  position: relative;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  display: none;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-height: 345px;
  min-height: 345px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.thisday-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.control:hover input~.control__indicator,
.control input:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #ccc;
}

.control input:checked~.control__indicator {
  background: #2aa1c0;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked~.control__indicator,
.control input:checked:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #0e647d;
}

.control input:disabled~.control__indicator {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.control__indicator:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control input:checked~.control__indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator:after {
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.control--radio input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  background: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-views-count {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font: normal normal normal 13px/1 FontAwesome;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #695454;
}

.control-views-count:before {
  margin: 4px;
}

.thisday-butt,
.thisday-btn {
  float: right;
}

.thisday-time {
  display: flex;
}

.thisday-content {
  clear: both;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) h3 {
  display: none !important;
}

.control-button__container {
  text-align: center;
}

.thisday-list__button {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.group-header {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.thisday-time #userdate {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.bs-native-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.thisday-form-butt {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.markNews {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews+.markNews_label__custom {
  background: #dad7d7;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews:checked+.markNews_label__custom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #58b790;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.markNews_label__custom:hover {
  background: #cfe330;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.markNews-label {
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-checked {
  background-color: #72f1638f;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #bdbdbd;
  margin: 0 3px;
}


/* label {
  transition-duration: .3s;
} */

.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):hover,
.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):focus {
  background-color: #9dd9f68f;
}
```

```html
<!-- Ответ для stackoverflow.com -->
<form id="senderForm" class="thisday-content" action="/edit" method="post" data-pjax="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="rjCmfkMlqVdNvBQfS-o8pZ9hs__jEMudiG_0MYzSMvLvUcwWKWOEMn74Q08Emg3R7xnDuaV6kuX9NbhJu-ZXhw==">
  <div class="thisday-time"><span style="margin: 0 auto;">Вы можете выбрать еще <strong id="countRadioButt">1</strong><strong id="notifSpan"> новость</strong> </span></div>
  <div class="thisday-container">
    <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2018</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-688204" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2018][]" value=" 688204" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-688204" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">"Должны есть грязь и отказаться быть человеком" – рабочий из КНДР во Владивостоке </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">16808                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2018</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-688251" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2018][]" value=" 688251" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-688251" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Новым главой фонда капремонта Приморья стал Александр Коваль </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">1660                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-585526" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 585526" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-585526" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Бизнес и предпринимательство в Приморье: цифры и факты </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">10871                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-585487" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 585487" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-585487" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Стали известны подробности перестрелки в воинской части в Приморье </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">10352                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-502181" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 502181" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-502181" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Loft №1 во Владивостоке: как в стенах студии выросли школа и "бюро" фотопутешествий </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">9624                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-502644" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 502644" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-502644" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Вратарь "Адмирала" и сборной России оказался в центре скандала с погоней и разбитой Audi </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">8728                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2015</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label label-checked">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-434479" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2015][]" value=" 434479" checked="checked" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-434479" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Гимнастка из Уссурийска представила Приморье на Чемпионате России </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3002                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2015</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-434475" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2015][]" value=" 434475" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-434475" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Госдума РФ приняла президентский проект амнистии в честь 70-летия Победы </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">2846                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2014</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-353121" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2014][]" value=" 353121" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-353121" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">"Хостельный" бум во Владивостоке: койко-место с wi-fi и видом на море за 500 рублей  </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">11523                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2014</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-353171" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2014][]" value=" 353171" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-353171" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Офисный планктон и бойцы поделят таинственный "замок" во Владивостоке   </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4068                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2013</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-272621" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2013][]" value=" 272621" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-272621" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Звонить Путину сегодня не буду, потому что разочарована в его ответах – Мария Соловьенко </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">6185                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2013</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-272475" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2013][]" value=" 272475" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-272475" class="markNews_label__custom"></label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Ребенок пропал на кладбище в Приморье </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4941</i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-button__container">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default thisday-form-butt" name="cansel-button" onclick="$(&quot;#btn_submit&quot;).prop('disabled','disabled')">Сбросить</button>

    <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="resume-button" disabled="disabled">Далее</button>

  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S - я еще пробовал `var coords = element.getBoundingClientRect();` тоже где то не там появляется(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку на элементе `.control-views-count` стоит `position:relative`, то для картинки позиция будет отсчитываться не относительно окна, а относительно родителя `.control-views-count`.

В связи с этим вам не надо рассчитывать положение, можно задать его статически.

Например:

```js
var image = document.createElement("img");

function showImage(element, event, url) {
  //console.log(element);
  image.className = "prepending-image";
  image.src = url;
  image.style.position = "absolute";
  image.style.right = "0";
  image.style.top = "20px";
  image.style.width = "100px";
  image.style.height = "100px";
  return element.prepend(image);
}

function hideImage(element, event) {
  element.removeChild(image);
}
```

```css
.ThisDay-default-index {
  position: relative;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  display: none;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-height: 345px;
  min-height: 345px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.thisday-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.control:hover input~.control__indicator,
.control input:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #ccc;
}

.control input:checked~.control__indicator {
  background: #2aa1c0;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked~.control__indicator,
.control input:checked:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #0e647d;
}

.control input:disabled~.control__indicator {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.control__indicator:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control input:checked~.control__indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator:after {
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.control--radio input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  background: #7b7b7b;
}

.control-views-count {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font: normal normal normal 13px/1 FontAwesome;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #695454;
}

.control-views-count:before {
  margin: 4px;
}

.thisday-butt,
.thisday-btn {
  float: right;
}

.thisday-time {
  display: flex;
}

.thisday-content {
  clear: both;
}

.control-group .group-header:not(:nth-child(1)) h3 {
  display: none !important;
}

.control-button__container {
  text-align: center;
}

.thisday-list__button {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.group-header {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.thisday-time #userdate {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.bs-native-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.thisday-form-butt {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.markNews {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews+.markNews_label__custom {
  background: #dad7d7;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.markNews:checked+.markNews_label__custom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #58b790;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.markNews_label__custom:hover {
  background: #cfe330;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.markNews-label {
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-checked {
  background-color: #72f1638f;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #bdbdbd;
  margin: 0 3px;
}


/* label {
  transition-duration: .3s;
} */

.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):hover,
.control-group__label:not(.label-checked):focus {
  background-color: #9dd9f68f;
}
```

```html
<!-- Ответ для stackoverflow.com -->
<form id="senderForm" class="thisday-content" action="/edit" method="post" data-pjax="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="rjCmfkMlqVdNvBQfS-o8pZ9hs__jEMudiG_0MYzSMvLvUcwWKWOEMn74Q08Emg3R7xnDuaV6kuX9NbhJu-ZXhw==">
  <div class="thisday-time"><span style="margin: 0 auto;">Вы можете выбрать еще <strong id="countRadioButt">1</strong><strong id="notifSpan"> новость</strong> </span></div>
  <div class="thisday-container">
    <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2018</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-688204" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2018][]" value=" 688204" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-688204" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">"Должны есть грязь и отказаться быть человеком" – рабочий из КНДР во Владивостоке </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">16808                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2018</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-688251" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2018][]" value=" 688251" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-688251" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Новым главой фонда капремонта Приморья стал Александр Коваль </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">1660                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-585526" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 585526" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-585526" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Бизнес и предпринимательство в Приморье: цифры и факты </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">10871                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2017</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-585487" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2017][]" value=" 585487" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-585487" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Стали известны подробности перестрелки в воинской части в Приморье </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">10352                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-502181" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 502181" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-502181" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Loft №1 во Владивостоке: как в стенах студии выросли школа и "бюро" фотопутешествий </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">9624                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2016</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-502644" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2016][]" value=" 502644" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-502644" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Вратарь "Адмирала" и сборной России оказался в центре скандала с погоней и разбитой Audi </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">8728                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2015</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label label-checked">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-434479" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2015][]" value=" 434479" checked="checked" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-434479" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Гимнастка из Уссурийска представила Приморье на Чемпионате России </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">3002                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2015</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-434475" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2015][]" value=" 434475" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-434475" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Госдума РФ приняла президентский проект амнистии в честь 70-летия Победы </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">2846                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2014</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-353121" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2014][]" value=" 353121" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-353121" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">"Хостельный" бум во Владивостоке: койко-место с wi-fi и видом на море за 500 рублей  </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">11523                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2014</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-353171" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2014][]" value=" 353171" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-353171" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Офисный планктон и бойцы поделят таинственный "замок" во Владивостоке   </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4068                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <h3 class="group-header">2013</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-272621" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2013][]" value=" 272621" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-272621" class="markNews_label__custom">  </label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Звонить Путину сегодня не буду, потому что разочарована в его ответах – Мария Соловьенко </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры" onmouseover="showImage(this, event, 'https://primamedia.ru/f/pict280x160.jpg')" onmouseout="hideImage(this, event)">6185                            </i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
        <h3 class="group-header">2013</h3>
        <label class="control-group__label ">
          <input type="radio" class="markNews" id="mark-radio-272475" style="width: 10%; float: left;" name="News[2013][]" value=" 272475" onclick=" $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', '')">
          <label for="mark-radio-272475" class="markNews_label__custom"></label>
        <span class="markNews-label">Ребенок пропал на кладбище в Приморье </span>
        <i class="control-views-count fa fa-eye" title="Просмотры">4941</i>
        </label>
        <div class=""></div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-button__container">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default thisday-form-butt" name="cansel-button" onclick="$(&quot;#btn_submit&quot;).prop('disabled','disabled')">Сбросить</button>

    <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="resume-button" disabled="disabled">Далее</button>

  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```